# Jupyter nbconvert slides render local images

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, nbconvert

I'm trying to convert my notebook into slides using the `jupyter nbconvert --to slides` command. This notebook contains images which are loaded from a local directory in a markdown cell like so `<img src="../assets/nn_basic_1.png" width="50%" height="50%">`

However, when I run the HTML file output from the conversion step, the images are not being displayed. In the terminal, I'm getting the following error: `403 GET /files/assets/nn_basic_1.png (::1): Blocking request from unknown origin`.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: It works when I add the `--post serve` flag to nbconvert command but I have to have an `assets` folder in the same directory as the slides document.